# Is methylsulfonylmethane (MSM) of any use to treat a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, tendons

Has [methylsulfonylmethane (MSM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methylsulfonylmethane) been shown to be of any use to treat a tendinopathy?

I looked for information on Google and Google Scholar but haven't found anything, so I'm not sure whether it means nobody looked at it or it has obvious no medical property.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.